# Changing web page content using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm looking for the best way to dynamically update a web page content using Javascript AJAX.

My first thought is to store various `div` layouts each describing a different page in various files, for example:

BasicDiv.div:

```
<div>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <button> A Button </button>
</div>
```

-Then create an empty `div` ,which content will be updated, inside the main webpage, then I make a `XMLHttpRequest` and update the `div.innerHtml` with the data loaded from the required file.

Is this a good way to use AJAX or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/simpleajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  type: "POST",
  data : { var:'val1',var2:'val2' }
}).done(function() { 
  $("<div>").innerHTML("done");
});
```